# Converting unsigned char to int and short

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

I am new to this, so I will begin by saying that while I was looking over some code I realized that this function doesn't make one bit of sense to me.

As you can see that this specific function uses bitwise operators to convert 4 unsigned char elements into integer.

//Converts a four-character array to an integer, using little-endian form

```
int toInt(const char* bytes) {
    return (int)(((unsigned char)bytes[3] << 24) |
                 ((unsigned char)bytes[2] << 16) |
                 ((unsigned char)bytes[1] << 8) |
                 (unsigned char)bytes[0]);
}

short toShort(const char* bytes) {
    return (short)(((unsigned char)bytes[1] << 8) |
                   (unsigned char)bytes[0]);
}
```

I already know how bitwise operators and how char uses 1 byte and int uses 4 bytes. Why would moving char bits 24 bits to the left and than just explicitly converting it to int convert it into an int? **Why is bitwise operators necessary for this function?**

This function goes beyond my comprehension, please explain this code and how it works or at least give me a link that throughly explains this.

I have looked everywhere for the explanation but could not find it.

This probably has a simple enough explanation.

Comment: Using operator << on a type shorter than int automatically promotes the input to an int. The final int cast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is bitwise operators necessary for this function?

Bitwise operators are used to "assemble" the four-byte number from four single-byte numbers.

Let's say you've got four 8-bit numbers, like this:

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
dddddddd
```

Shifts give you this:

```
aaaaaaaa000000000000000000000000
00000000bbbbbbbb0000000000000000
0000000000000000cccccccc00000000
000000000000000000000000dddddddd
```

Bitwise operator `OR` lets you make a single number from these four parts, because `OR`-ing any bit `x` with a zero produces `x`. If you align four-byte numbers like shown above, there is only one non-zero bit in each position, so bitwise `OR`s produce the desired result:

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd
```

Comment: I tried to sum up this answer in a comment, but I couldn't. Nice answer.

Comment: in this case how do unsigned character shift 24, 16, 8 bits to get integers? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Snake: fair question. Read "Conversions" under http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic: "before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes integral promotion."

Comment: @Snake it's because of integral operation promotion rules from C. `<<` will always promote both operands to at least `int` before doing its work.

Comment: @Snake That's a good point: shifting is an integer operation, so it casts its operands to `int` before the shift, so an eight-bit `aaaaaaaa` becomes `000000000000000000000000aaaaaaaa` before shifting.